# How to fetch images from remote urls and display them in different view?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter

When i click on the button from bottom view i want to display all the images from the list on the top view.

The error i get is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'image'"

I can change the label to text but i want to display all the images i get.
After i get it up and running i will try to use more functions to be more readable but for now i want to do it this way

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

win = tk.Tk()


def GreenBrigadeStickers():


    URL_list = ["https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/296647089/Image+1.png?auto=format&fit=max&h=390&w=390","https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/295852698/Image+1.png?auto=format&fit=max&h=390&w=390","https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/295852698/Image+1.png?auto=format&fit=max&h=390&w=390","https://assets.bigcartel.com/product_images/295852698/Image+1.png?auto=format&fit=max&h=390&w=390"]

    current_row = 0
    current_column = 0

    for url in URL_list:

        u = urlopen(url)
        raw_data = u.read()
        u.close()

        im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

        
        test = a.config(image=photo)
        test.image = photo
        test.grid(row = current_row, column = current_column)
        current_row += 1
        if (current_row >= 4):
            current_column += 1
            current_row = 0
        return test


#view top

wrapper1 = tk.LabelFrame(win)

mycanvas = tk.Canvas(wrapper1)
mycanvas.pack(side="left", fill='both', expand = "yes")

yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(wrapper1,orient="vertical", command = mycanvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack(side="right", fill = "y")

mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

mycanvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: mycanvas.configure( scrollregion = mycanvas.bbox("all")))

myframe = tk.Frame(mycanvas)
mycanvas.create_window((0,0),window=myframe, anchor="nw")

wrapper1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=10)
a = tk.Label(myframe)
a.pack()

# VIEW BOTTOM
wrapper2 = tk.LabelFrame(win)



mycanvas2 = tk.Canvas(wrapper2)
mycanvas2.pack(side="left", fill='both', expand = "yes")

yscrollbar2 = tk.Scrollbar(wrapper2,orient="vertical", command = mycanvas2.yview)
yscrollbar2.pack(side="right", fill = "y")

mycanvas2.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar2.set)

mycanvas2.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: mycanvas2.configure( scrollregion = mycanvas2.bbox("all")))

myframe2 = tk.Frame(mycanvas2)
mycanvas2.create_window((0,0),window=myframe2, anchor="nw")

wrapper2.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=10, pady=10)
    

button1=tk.Button(myframe2, text="AICI", command = GreenBrigadeStickers)
button1.grid(row=1,column=0)

win.geometry("500x500")

win.resizable(False,False)
win.title("MyScroller")




win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```py
test = a.config(image=photo)
test.image = photo
test.grid(row = current_row, column = current_column)
current_row += 1
if (current_row >= 4):
    current_column += 1
    current_row = 0
return test
```

to this:

```py
a.config(image=photo)
a.image = photo
a.grid(row = current_row, column = current_column)
current_row += 1
if (current_row >= 4):
    current_column += 1
    current_row = 0
return a
```

`<tkinter.Label>.config` always returns `None`. I think you wanted to use the actual `<tkinter.Label>` that you called `a`.